# PHP Loop for multidimensional array index

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having trouble to make a tree.

```
<?php
$x = [];
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
    //What I need to do?
}

print_r($x);
```

I would like to get an Output like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [3] => Array
                                (
                                    [4] => 
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Please, guide me how to do that?

Comment: Why loop and not recursion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can alter the way of the `for` loop to be decreasing and then do:

```
$x = [];
for($i=4;$i>=0;$i--){
    $x = [$i => $x];
}
```

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/v0l2k)